# Move through divs using the keyboard arrows on react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

A while ago I came across a jQuery plugin in which I was able to move through divs, menus, images ... using the directional arrows on the keyboard.

I've searched a lot about it but I can't find anything.

I need to do this in react, but I can't find any tutorial and I'm kind of lost in this subject

[Here is an example](https://tv-navigation-test.netlify.app) of a screen that I need to develop

**Remembering that I need to do this in react**

Comment: link is broken, stack**overflow** is not the appropriate site for this kind of questions.

Comment: Corrected the link @GabrielePetrioli